# IconData isn't a type when Generation Flutter icons

Tags: flutter, dart

i am generation a custom icons using [fluttericon](https://www.fluttericon.com/) but after generation i keep getting error that `IconData isn't a type`  which i cant wrap my head around it...

```
  static const IconData comment = IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData zoom_out = IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData zoom_in = IconData(0xe802, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData zap = IconData(0xe803, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
```

[image: the error in images]

Comment: Do you have `import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';` or `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes, i import it@Abion47

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get`?